# Convert Raster to Vector for forest area claculation

Tags: arcgis-pro, shape-area

I have done my image classification for forested and non-forested areas. Now, I want to convert from raster to vector (polygon) in order to vew the attribute table and calculate the total area of forested areas.
How do I do this in ArcGIS pro?

Comment: Use the geoprocessing tool *Raster to Polygon* https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm, if you choose a shapefile for the output you can calculate the area using *Calculate Geometry Atttributes* https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm; geodatabase features automatically have their area calculated.

Comment: You have an [X Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You don't need to convert from raster to vector in order to calculate the total area of forested areas.